# rails generate scaffold but prevent the model file from being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked over the documentation at `rails generate scaffold -h` but am still stumped. I want to create all the files from the scaffold generator *except* the model file.

Example:

```
rails generate scaffold User --no-model
```

This as it is does not work but what I would like to happen is that the `user.rb` file is prevented from being created within the models directory.

Comment: Are you attempting to use Devise for Authentication?

Comment: No.  I have just already created the model file so I don't want to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!  You just need to include `--skip` to tell rails that for any conflicting files to just ignore creating those files.

**Example**: say I already have the file `user.rb` inside my models directory:

```
rails generate scaffold User --skip
```

With the `--skip` option rails knows to skip creating the `user.rb` file, as well as all other already existing files that the scaffold command would generate for this resource.